# The underlying connection was closed when using a WSDL web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to consume this WSDL service:

[Transit Time Service](http://www.estes-express.com/transittime/services/TransitTimeService?wsdl)

I successfully connect and get a response the first time but on subsequent calls I receive the exception:

The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.

I overrode the GetWebRequest in the reference.cs file as such:

```
 protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
 {
     HttpWebRequest webRequest =  (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
     webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
     return webRequest;
 }
```

This hasn't yielded any improvement.  I am at a loss as to what options I have now, does anyone have any other ideas that I could try so that I may avoid this error?

Thanks in advance!

Josh

Comment: You could ask the owners of the service why they're closing the connection...

Answer (score 0):

This usually indicates an issue with the service, as it is unexpectedly closing the connection from the server side.  Are you transmitting large amounts of data or using a long running task?

Comment: No, I have pretty much spoken to their development group until I am blue in the face.  I also came to the conclusion that it was their service after running quite a few tests using fiddler.  Of course it comes down to them saying they can't find any problem so I am just left high and dry.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried service on my playground project. It works well.

You can try increase inner channel timeout value. And retry again please. If you using service pattern, your service should construct it with timeout. Inner channel can be null if client configuration is wrong or bad. Handle it.

```
using TransitTimeService;

transitPortTypeClient transitPortTypeClient = new(endpointConfiguration: TransitTimeService.transitPortTypeClient.EndpointConfiguration.transitPortType);

transitPortTypeClient.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

serviceRequest serviceRequest = new()
{
    shipDate = DateTime.Now
};

serviceRequest1 serviceRequest1 = new()
{
    auth = new AuthenticationType()
    {
        user = "test",
        password = "test"
    },
    serviceRequest = serviceRequest
};

var result = await transitPortTypeClient.calculateAsync(serviceRequest1);

Console.WriteLine(result.serviceResult.Item);

await transitPortTypeClient.CloseAsync();
```